# Multible Transactions right after opening Trade or Method 0x110bbd8d

Tags: tokens, etherscan, bot, automate

I've been looking at the latest pairs on dextools.io lately and I've noticed that it's becoming more and more common that even when the trading pair is only a few minutes old, there are already several hundred token holders?

In the following I have attached two examples that correspond to the description

Example1: https://etherscan.io/advanced-filter?tkn=0xCe0740BA3fC551c25A2b48B85Bf70D173F602b42&txntype=2&p=142

Example2: https://etherscan.io/token/0x6e08e8353327290e5e571bf7a7e03525fa6cdac6

Example 3: method "0x110bbd8d" https://etherscan.io/tx/0xce1ce6a23dc29c15d0132b7543104341e824d9c935279eabdf9cb1bf2a186e30#eventlog

I have included example 3 because I have come across this method almost always in the transaction histories mentioned, unfortunately I could not understand its use

many thanks for any help

Comment: you need the source code of the contract to understand its use, or disassemble the contract from the binary code. this is a private contract (source code unpublished), so it is not likely you are going to obtain it